# I am trying to get access token and verify the token ,but I am getting errors as expressed below

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, jwt, fastapi, pydantic

`
def create_access_token(data: dict):
to_encode = data.copy()

```
    expire = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTE)
    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})

    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)

    return encoded_jwt


def verify_access_token(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)], credentials_exception):

    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        id: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)] = payload.get("user_id")
        if id is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = schemas.TokenData(id=id)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception

    return token_data


def get_current_user(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)], db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                                    detail=f"Could not validate credentials", headers={"WWW- Authenticate": "Bearer"})

    token = verify_access_token(token, credentials_exception)

    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == token.id).first()

    return user`
```

`i am getting error in oauth2.get_current_user() not sure what is wrong with the code
error: str type cannot be assigned to TokenData

ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last

File "B:\FastAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\dependencies\utils.py", line 586, in solve_dependencies
solved = await run_in_threadpool(call, **sub_values)

File "B:\FastAPI\app\oauth2.py", line 49, in get_current_user
token = verify_access_token(token, credentials_exception)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "B:\FastAPI\app\oauth2.py", line 38, in verify_access_token
token_data = schemas.TokenData(id=id)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "B:\FastAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.py", line 150, in **init**
**pydantic_self**.**pydantic_validator**.validate_python(data, self_instance=**pydantic_self**)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for TokenData id

Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=1, input_type=int]`

Comment: Error message answered clearly. `TokenData.id` must be type  str but got int.